# SQL - Find all related tags?

Tags: sql, relationship, tagging

I have a relation tag table like below. Relation `tag_id` "1" exists for all three `node_id` (1,2,3).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relation` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `node_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `relation` (`id`, `tag_id`, `node_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 3, 1),
(4, 4, 1),
(5, 1, 2),
(6, 3, 2),
(7, 4, 2),
(8, 5, 2),
(9, 1, 3),
(10, 3, 3),
(11, 5, 3),
(12, 6, 3);
```

Using tag_id "1" as the starting point, how can I get a list of all tags ordered by number of occurrence? For example, the tag_id "3" exists in all three node_id records - while the tag_id 4 only exists twice (node_id 1 & 2).

The results should look like this:

```
tag_id  count
3       3
4       2
5       2
6       1
2       1
```

**Update:** Sorry, I didn't explain it good enough. When I said "tag_id "1" as the starting point", I meant if I searched for relations to tag_id - how could I order them by occurrence?

I want to find all tag_ids related to tag_id one ordered by count. This will allow me to see all the tag_id numbers used along with tag_id 1. Continuing with the example above - tag_id "3" should be the most used tag_id for node_ids with tag_id 1.

**Update 2:** I think I found an [answer here](http://www.ferdychristant.com/blog//archive/DOMM-7Q5SS2).

```
SELECT tag_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM relation
WHERE tag_id != 1 AND node_id IN
(
    SELECT node_id FROM relation WHERE tag_id = 1
)
GROUP BY tag_id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Is this method better than a LEFT JOIN? Is there anything I can do to improve it's speed?

Comment: `select tag_id, count(*) from relation where tag_id <> 1 group by tag_id`? It returns your desired results but I'm not sure where the nodes enter into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select tag_id, Count(*) as TagCount
from relation
where tag_id <> 1
group by tag_id
order by Count(*) desc
```

Comment: +1 good start, but this simply sorts all records in the table *except* for tag_id 1. I'm looking for only records which are related to records which *have* tag_id 1.

Comment: How are the rows related to each other?

Comment: Thanks amit_g, despite my invalid question (based on the answer I wanted), your query helped me find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

```
SELECT tag_id, COUNT(*)
FROM relation
GROUP BY tag_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
```